# Lua - check if cursor is inside of a button

Tags: button, lua, position

so basically I wrote these lines of code to check if my cursor is inside of a button aka mousover. It works perfect, but I really don't like the way I wrote the **if-statement**.

```
--cursor       = table containing x and y value of cursor
--self         = table containing x and y value of button
--self.W       = returns width of button
--self.H       = return height of button   

function mousover(cursor)
    if cursor.x >= self.x                 --if cursor is inside of button from left side
    and cursor.x <= self.x + self.W       --if cursor is inside of button from right side
    and cursor.y >= self.y                --if cursor is inside of button from top side
    and cursor.y <= self.y + self.H then  --if cursor is inside of button from bottom side
       doSomething()
    end
```

Is there a better way to write this **if-statement**? Maybe like do 1 calculation to get the boundaries of the button and do 1 check, instead of 4 to see if the cursor is inside? Not sure how I can improve this, if you have a better idea, pls share.

**REQUIREMENT: It needs to be coded in plain Lua, no extensions/plugins/etc are allowed.**

Comment: the code seems fine to me (maybe abstract it into a function) but since this is working, it should be on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I initially stated in a comment:

No there is no better way.

This is a traditional bounding box check. A bounding box has four sides, therefore you need to check four conditions.

Think about what the code is doing and why it is doing it, then you should realize that it really needs to do everything that it is currently doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
function mousover(cursor)
   if math.floor((cursor.x - self.x)/self.W)^2 + 
      math.floor((cursor.y - self.y)/self.H)^2 == 0 then
      -- DoSomething()
   end
end
```

Comment: I doubt this is "better". It might be less code, but it's less readable and comes with less performance.